# How to disable automatic http requests in WebView2

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, webview2

When the user's mouse hovers (not click) over a hyperlink, WebView2 control in Winforms or WPF will automatically send an http request.

```
<html>
  <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us//">Visit</a><br/>
</html>
```

Here is the result monitored using Fiddler:
[image]

The behavior can also be reproduced in Edge:
[image]

How could we disable such automatic http requests?